# analysis of groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe 'order_data' containing details about daily orders with one column: 'date' in datetime format and a second column: 'size' where three the three sizes of orders can be 'A', 'B', or 'C'.

I would like to analyse for each 5-minute interval, the order size split, showing their corresponding percentages (e.g. 18:30-18:35: A=50%, B=30%, C=20%).

So far I have been able to group the orders by 5-minute intervals and count them using pandas "groupby" as follows:

```
grouped=order_data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5T')]).count()
```

But I am not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: It includes the date.

Answer (score 2):

`group` on both 5-minute intervals and the `'size'` column. Then `divide` by the sum within the time interval to normalize.

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10000
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2011-01-01', freq='1.15S', periods=N),
                   'size': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], N)})
```

#### Code:

```
gp = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5T'), 'size']).size().unstack(-1)
gp = gp.divide(gp.sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100)

#size                         A          B          C
#date                                                
#2011-01-01 00:00:00  36.781609  34.099617  29.118774
#2011-01-01 00:05:00  36.015326  28.352490  35.632184
#2011-01-01 00:10:00  30.268199  32.950192  36.781609
#2011-01-01 00:15:00  29.885057  37.164751  32.950192
#...
```

---

Alternatively with normalized `value_counts`, grouping only on 5-minute intervals:

```
gp = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5T'))['size']
        .value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(-1)
        .multiply(100))
```